# Finding the Nth key in a TreeMap most efficiently

Tags: performance, scala, treemap

I have a Scala TreeMap that automatically sorts the keys.  What I would like to know is if there is a more performant way of finding the Nth key in the map than the following example:

```
treeMap.take(N).lastKey
```

Thanks,
Bruce

**EDIT:**
I created a small test using the following code:

```
class Test {
    var treeMap = new scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Double,String]()
    val numberOfEntries = 1000
    (0 until numberOfEntries) map { i => {treeMap += {i.toDouble -> i.toString}}}
    val iterations = 2000
    var N = 1

    while(N < numberOfEntries) {

        // my original version
        var i = 0
        val start1 = System.nanoTime()
        while(i < iterations) {
            i += 1
            val v = treeMap.take(N).lastKey
        }
        val end1 = System.nanoTime()
        val elapsed1 = end1 - start1

        // Daniel's suggestion
        i = 0
        val start2 = System.nanoTime()
        while(i < iterations) {
            i += 1
            val v = treeMap.keysIterator.drop(N - 1).next
        }
        val end2 = System.nanoTime()
        val elapsed2 = end2 - start2

        println("N = %d, elapsed1 = %d, elapsed2 = %d".format(N,elapsed1,elapsed2))
        N += 50
    }

}

object Test {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val test = new Test
  }
}
```

It appears that Daniel's suggestion is indeed better

**Results**

```
N = 1, elapsed1 = 956492000, elapsed2 = 700300000
N = 51, elapsed1 = 1103271000, elapsed2 = 936045000
N = 101, elapsed1 = 1286896000, elapsed2 = 1041744000
N = 151, elapsed1 = 1368854000, elapsed2 = 1199766000
N = 201, elapsed1 = 1584878000, elapsed2 = 1333284000
N = 251, elapsed1 = 1790965000, elapsed2 = 1468806000
N = 301, elapsed1 = 2052298000, elapsed2 = 1649021000
N = 351, elapsed1 = 2294625000, elapsed2 = 1819525000
N = 401, elapsed1 = 2529855000, elapsed2 = 1961699000
N = 451, elapsed1 = 2762582000, elapsed2 = 2100127000
N = 501, elapsed1 = 2977613000, elapsed2 = 2232108000
N = 551, elapsed1 = 3211812000, elapsed2 = 2384940000
N = 601, elapsed1 = 3437116000, elapsed2 = 2539431000
N = 651, elapsed1 = 3652749000, elapsed2 = 2650910000
N = 701, elapsed1 = 3900431000, elapsed2 = 2807085000
N = 751, elapsed1 = 4123141000, elapsed2 = 2934904000
N = 801, elapsed1 = 4337909000, elapsed2 = 3060158000
N = 851, elapsed1 = 4554490000, elapsed2 = 3188378000
N = 901, elapsed1 = 4768488000, elapsed2 = 3306528000
N = 951, elapsed1 = 4978839000, elapsed2 = 3413813000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immutable `SortedSet` and `SortedMap` went got overhauled recently. Version 2.10 will have a number of improvements, including improvements to finding the first and last elements and `take`, `drop`, `slice`.

Right now, the solution you propose, `take(N).lastKey` is not particularly efficient. Instead, I'd do `iterator.drop(n - 1).next._1`. It's not particularly efficient either, and I'd benchmark both solutions before picking one.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the overhaul.  Also, thanks for giving me an alternative to explore, whether or not it proves to be an improvement in the short run.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've posted an edit showing the relative performance of your suggestion versus my version.  Yours appears to be better. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

Scala and TreeMaps aside, I am not sure that there is a better than O(n) algorithm for finding the Nth item in a tree.  For any node M, in order to determine how many children M has you need to descend into each child.  Therefore to count the first N nodes you need to descend to the first N leaves.

Comment: depends on what sort of tree. If you have some balancing guarantee and each nodes keep tracks of how many elements are below, you could certainly get an O(log(N)) bound